# mod_rewrite with .htaccess to spoof subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a django app running on a subdomain, subdomain.domain.com/appname, but I don't want the app name to show up in any of my urls.  I have accomplished this via .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !appname
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appname/$1 [L]
```

This accompishes the case where the requested url is subdomain.domain.com/home and it is served from subdomain.domain.com/appname/home.

However, I'd also like to accomplish the reverse, where the requested url is subdomain.domain.com/appname/home, and the displayed url changes to subdomain.domain.com/home, which then triggers the rule above and is served from subdomain.domain.com/appname/home

I tried the following but got an error that I have a loop

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} appname
RewriteRule ^appname/(.*)$ /$1 [N,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !appname
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appname/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without the 'N' flag:

`'next|N' (next round)

Re-run the rewriting process (starting again with the first rewriting rule). This time, the URL to match is no longer the original URL, but rather the URL returned by the last rewriting rule. This corresponds to the Perl next command or the continue command in C. Use this flag to restart the rewriting process - to immediately go to the top of the loop.

Be careful not to create an infinite loop!`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html